# Easy if problem in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, if-statement

i try to copy the second line from a txt, that works great problem is now i try to make an  if-statement that check the txt, is there something in line 2.

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", True)
 MyFile.WriteLine("" + LastMessage + "")
 MyFile.Close

 rownumber = 0

 file = "testfile.txt"
 Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set File = fs.OpenTextFile(file , 1, true)
 Do While not file.AtEndOfStream
  rownumber = rownumber+1
  row = (file.ReadLine)
  if rownumber = 2 then
   new =  row
   msgbox row
  end if
  If row = 0 Then
   msgbox "nothing found"
  else
   msgbox "found"
  end if
 Loop
```

The if row = 0 will not work, has some one an idea?

Error Message: Incompatible types: '[string:""]'

Line: If row = 0 Then

Regards,
matthias

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? Are you getting an error? What do you expect to happen? What isn't happening?

Comment: it comes the error: Incompatible types: '[string:""]'

Comment: Two unrelated hints: 1. I think you cannot use `new` as a variable name since it's a keyword. 2. Use the `&` operator for string concatenation, not `+`.

Comment: Also I think that you posted two scripts (one for writing, one for reading) inside a single code block, which is quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a string to a number - the content of `row` will be a string, so there is a type mismatch when comparing it to a number.

Try this to find out if the line contains the number 0:

```
If row = "0" Then
```

If you want to know if the row is empty, try this:

```
If row = "" Then
```

Answer (score 2):

`row` is a string because the `ReadLine` method returns a string. Probably you want to say `If row = ""` or `If Len(row) = 0` instead.

Here is an improved version of your scripts:

- Script for writing:

  ```
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set File = FSO.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", True)
  File.WriteLine LastMessage  ' Why "" + ... + ""?
  File.Close
  ```
- Script for reading:

  ```
  RowNumber = 0
  FileName = "testfile.txt"
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1, True)
  Do Until File.AtEndOfStream
      RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
      Row = File.ReadLine
      If RowNumber = 2 Then
          NewRow = Row   ' NewRow is nowhere used
          MsgBox Row
      End If
      If Len(Row) = 0 Then
          MsgBox "nothing found"
      Else
          MsgBox "found"
      End If
  Loop
  ```